# How can I get my program looks like QtDemo?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

How can I edit my program to have a look like QtDemo ?

I am using Qt 4.7.

Thanks

Comment: `QtDemo` is **open-source**, so you might take a look at the code. Otherwise, your question is too vague (and likely to be closed). What do you want to achieve **exactly** and what issues did you encounter doing it ?

Comment: In fact I would like to get my application looks like QtDemo : There is a left menu with buttons( how can I do it) and in the right there is a widget that change relatively with the button clicked( How can I make this effect ? which widget shall I use?)

Comment: Finally I would like to know how to edit the style of my application to looks like the style of QtDemo

Answer (score 2):

A Qt installation often includes the demo code. Start with the source code from QtDemo, strip out the demo part and then add your code.